# How can I get sessionStorage information with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a field on the Session Storage of a tab with some information. I want to my google extension to copy to CLipboard or show on some HTML so the user can copy.

I've created a simples extension like this on the JS:

```
function renderStatus(statusText) {
  document.getElementById('status').textContent = statusText;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      renderStatus("Bearer " + sessionStorage.getItem("userToken"));
});
```

But the return is always "Bearer undefined" but if i do the same on the console ir works.

Thanks!!

Comment: Where is this code running? IE, in a context-script, newtab, background?

Comment: Normal Google Chrome Extension. I've used this project as an example to start: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/tutorials/getstarted.zip

Comment: Where do you set userToken in sessionStorage?

Comment: This is on the webapp running, is not set by the Extension.